# Does Unbound re-use TLS connections for DoT forwarding?

Tags: dns, dot

Unbound has the option to use DNS over TLS as an upstream (through the [forward-tls-upstream](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/) setting).

CludFlare's *1.1.1.1* service offers this; [also through TOR](https://blog.cloudflare.com/welcome-hidden-resolver/).

My question is whether

- Unbound will **open a new TLS** connection for each request (in which case my queries will be lost in the endless soup of all the others using the same TOR exit node), or
- Unbound will **re-use an existing TLS** connection (in which case CloudFlare can build a neat bucket of only the queries coming from my router - making the TOR tunneling part useless).

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but the spec has some other interesting privacy considerations that may allow you to be fingerprinted anyway: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8484#section-8.2

Comment: Reading your first link, it looks like DNS over TLS, not HTTPS. The DoT spec does encourage long-running connections for performance reasons though, so I'd wager that's how it's implemented. Would need to look at the code probably.

Comment: In many cases they encourage keep-alive with HTTPS because the intial handshake + asymmetric part has a hefty cost.

Comment: @multithr3at3d That's why the TOR part is important.(For the DNS server not to be able to make a logical connection - originating IP - between the queries).

Comment: @multithr3at3d I can re-tag the question if you can create a DoT tag :)

Comment: I took care of it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is a ticket saying that Unbound does not re-use TLS connections, but it is planned.
https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/issues/47